# How to create generic delegate from a method within an object

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I'm Trying to create a generic delegate like this:

```
Func<string, string, IEnumerable<MyPOCO>> del  = 
WCFServiceInstance.GetLabs(SessionStateService.Var1,SessionStateService.Var2));
```

but it seems because GetLabs is within a WCFServiceInstace the Func delegate just thinks I'm passing it an IEnumerable rather than

```
Func<string, string, IEnumerable<MyPOCO>>
```

which is what I'm trying to pass it.

Comment: Does GetLabs return a function? How do you want to call `del` (with which arguments)?

Comment: What is the method signature of GetLabs?

Comment: No it returns IEnumerable<MyPOCO>

Comment: Method signature of GetLabs is public IEnumerable<MyPOCO> GetLabs(string var1, string var2){...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something else wrong with your approach.
Are the two arguments supposed to be always `SessionStateService.Var1` and `SessionStateService.Var2`? Or will those be the delegate's arguments?

If you want them to be the delegate's parameters:

```
Func<string, string, IEnumerable<MyPOCO>> del  =
   WCFServiceInstance.GetLabs;

del(SessionStateService.Var1, SessionStateService.Var2);
```

If you want the method be invoked with those specific values, use a closure instead:

```
Func<IEnumerable<MyPOCO>> del  =
   () => WCFServiceInstance.GetLabs(SessionStateService.Var1, SessionStateService.Var2);

del();
```

Bear in mind that if you use a closure, `SessionStateService.Var1` and `SessionStateService.Var2` will be evaluated when the delegate is called (line 2), not when it is declared (line 1). So, if you pass this second delegate around and call it later, the values of the arguments might have changed.

If you want to prevent that, you can use eager evaluation, as exemplified by @knittl in the comments:

```
string var1 = SessionStateService.Var1,
       var2 = SessionStateService.Var2;

Func<IEnumerable<MyPOCO>> del = () => WCFServiceInstance.GetLabs(var1, var2);
```

Comment: If you don't want `Var1` and `Var2` to be evaluated at call time, use `string var1 = SessionStateService.Var1, var2 = SessionStateService.Var2; var del = () => WCFServiceInstance.GetLabs(var1, var2);`

Comment: Yes correct I was getting confused between how I get the arguments into the delegate definition

Comment: Can I also pass a function with it's 2 arguments into another object like this?

Comment: @BarryMcDermid Do you mean, create a delegate, which calls a method with 2 fixed arguments, and pass that delegate to another method (of another object)? If so, yes: use the third approach.

Comment: Yes, managed to pass the entire Method with 2 parms in as a closure like this SessionStateService.Labs = CacheManager.GetData(() => WCFService.GetLabs(SessionStateService.var1, SessionStateService.var1)); great stuff!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Func<string, string, IEnumerable<MyPOCO>> del = WCFServiceInstance.GetLabs;
```

and then use it like:

```
del(SessionStateService.Var1,SessionStateService.Var2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
Func<string, string, IEnumerable<MyPOCO>> del = WCFServiceInstance.GetLabs;
```

That is, assuming WCFServiceInstance.GetLabs has the following signature:

```
IEnumerable<MyPOCO> WCFServiceInstance.GetLabs(string, string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a lambda expression to  partially apply the function, fixing the first two arguments:

```
Func<IEnumerable<MyPOCO>> del  =
  () => WCFServiceInstance.GetLabs(
    SessionStateService.Var1,
    SessionStateService.Var2);
```

Call as `del()`.

Comment: Note that `Var1` and `Var2` contain the current values, so if you update their values you will use the updated values in your function call. Store them in a local variable first if you want them to be fixed (closures are tricky).